# Fan Needs 12V, only have 9V

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, computers, battery-operated

I recently bought a 12V small computer fan(about 1"X1") and it was running rather slow when I checked it with a 9V. The package says that the fan requires 12V to run at an optimized speed, so is there a way/circuit that I can use/make that increases the voltage from 9 to 12?

Comment: What you are looking for is a dc-dc step-up converter. I hope you don't try to feed your fan with a 9V block battery?

Comment: http://www.ebay.com/bhp/dc-dc-adjustable-step-up

Comment: @Botnic hehe at least it's cheap as dirt

Comment: The bigger bottleneck is the current that the 9V battery can provide. Boosting to 12V will only make that problem worse.

Comment: The battery is not going to stay at 9V either when under load. I'd estimate the fan will draw 0.1A @ 12 V (1.2W) and your 9V battery is unlikely to exceed 0.05A @ 8V (0.4W). 8xAA battery might be a better solution. A NiMH battery easily delivers that that 0.1A.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, a 9V battery won't produce enough current to power a small computer fan. Using any type of step-up circuitry is only going to increase the current demand on the battery. Even if you could get it to work, you'd get only 3-4 hours runtime at most. The short answer is that a 9V battery just doesn't have enough juice to power a computer fan.

Answer (score 2):

Use an inverting buck regulator to create -3V and wire your fan between -3v and +9V. Maybe one of these: -

[image]

It's got a -5V output but that can be made -3V by choosing appropriate values for R3 and R4

Answer (score 1):

"Simple Switchers" (brand name) are easy to use, buck or boost, very efficient switch mode power supplies - boosting the output current should be easy, but I'll let the experts answer that, otherwise I'll get into hot water.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to return the fan you bought, and get one intended to run from 9 V.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Jip: Actually, it properly addresses the overall problem, just not the single solution the OP is envisioning.

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting the 9V battery and 2AA(1.5V) battery in series to produce 12V.
Or you can try making a boost converter circuit which is a bit more complicated but will step-up or step-down your voltage in a circuit. 
You can learn more about boost-converters [here](http://www.learnabout-electronics.org/PSU/psu32.php).